# What does enabling "Data Protection" in iOS exactly imply?

Tags: ios, security, keychain, data-protection

I'm looking for information about `Data Protection` capability in Apple's documentation, but I hardly found any. I'd appreciate that someone could make me clear some questions:

1. Does enabling that capability require any more actions from the developer?
2. Must I have something into account if I enable this capability when submitting the app to the `App Store`?
3. I could access the `Keychain` in my app without having `Data Protection` enabled... this looks weird... shouldn't be `Data Protection` enabled to access `Keychain`?
4. What files are / could be protected by enabling the capability?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) the information.

1. No, other than turning it on.
2. No, I don't believe so.
3. It only affects how files are stored by your app, and no other aspect of your app.
4. Anything you like.  Nudie pictures of your wife, your bank account details, etc.